# How to update this BackgroundWorker to async/await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to convert some BackgroundWorkers to the newer async/await, and both my coworker and I have no idea how to do the following: Currently I have code that looks roughly like this:

```
// Note the override. This method isn't async and I don't own the base class
protected override void MyMethod()
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DoStuff1();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    DoStuff2();
}
```

I'd like to update the code to look like this, but obviously this won't work because I need to call it from a synchronous method:

```
// Again note the override. This method isn't async and I don't own the base class
protected override void MyNewMethod()
{
    // Error: "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method."
    await Task.Run((Action)DoStuff1);
    DoStuff2();
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this? Am I going about it the wrong way?
The main issue is that fact that MyMethod() is not supposed to be async, but any other posts I've found just say to change it to async. Even if I could, that would mean the method that calls it would also have to be async, and the method that calls that method would be async, etc. So basically everything becomes async just to support this one method. I'm sure there is a better way.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You are going about the wrong way.  What you can do is use a WaitHandle to block (use WaitOne) and have the BackgroundWorker set the WaitHandle when work is completed.

Comment: I don't want the code to block. The purpose is to do a long database load (5-10 seconds) without freezing the UI.

Comment: Your original code should do that.  It looks like you need background worker to complete before DoStuff.  So you do need to block.

Comment: The original code works fine, RunWorkerAsync does not block the thread it is called from.

Comment: You can just add "async" after "override" which does not change the signature of the method – the async keyword is basically just a marker to enable the await keyword. Alternatively, you could write "Task.Run(DoStuff1).ContinueWith(task => DoStuff2(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);" which omits the asynchronous/await keyword but is functionally equivalent to what you have written. Yes, the method cannot be awaited but you don't need to considering it doesn't look like anybody has waited for your BackgroundWorker before.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward translation of your existing code would be something like this:

```
protected override async void MyNewMethod()
{
  try
  {
    await Task.Run(() => DoStuff1());
    DoSuccessStuff2();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    DoErrorStuff2();
  }
}
```

Ideally, you should [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). The drawbacks to this solution is that `MyNewMethod` is now a "top-level" method - it has to handle all its own errors and everything. However, since your old BGW code *had the same problem*, this is at least a step in the right direction.

> So basically everything becomes async just to support this one method. I'm sure there is a better way.

It can be awkward to get there, but asynchronous code is *much* easier to compose and test if you do use "`async` all the way". Something like this:

```
protected override async Task MyNewMethodAsync()
{
  await Task.Run(() => DoStuff1());
  DoSuccessStuff2();
}
```

This kicks error handling up the chain to whoever calls `MyNewMethodAsync`. In addition, `MyNewMethodAsync` is now testable and composable from other asynchronous methods.